# try() not applying expression in the case where there's no potential error

Tags: r

```
lookup <- list(
  'miles_per_gallon' = 'mpg',
  'cylinder' = 'cyl'
)


df1 <- mtcars
df2 <- NULL

# function to rename columns based on the lookup above
index_name <- function(df, lookup) {
  i1 <- unlist(lookup) %in% names(df)
  names_lookup_sub <- lookup[i1]
  df %>% rename(!!! lookup[i1])
}


df1 %>% index_name(lookup) %>% glimpse # works as expected
df2 %>% index_name(lookup) %>% glimpse #  Error in UseMethod("rename_") : no applicable method for 'rename_' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

wanted to use try:

```
df2 %>% try(index_name(lookup)) %>% glimpse # Returns NULL, no error message. Good
```

but

```
df1 %>% try(index_name(lookup)) %>% glimpse # no error message, but the name changes were not applies
```

Basically, I would like to apply by function `index_name` to a list of dataframes. Sometimes there will be a NULL dataframe, in this case just pass over it rather than stop and throw an error message.

Why does my function not seem to get applied when nested within `try()`? It seems to work fine when not nested within `try()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having here is that the `%>%` operator places the left hand side as the first argument of the outermost function.

Therefore these four expressions are equivalent:

```
df1 %>% try(index_name(lookup)) %>% glimpse 
df1 %>% try(.,index_name(lookup)) %>% glimpse 
df1 %>% try(.) %>% glimpse
df1 %>% try %>% glimpse
```

You need:

```
df1 %>% {try(index_name(.,lookup))} %>% glimpse
```

With `{}` we can explicitly define where the left hand side is applied in the right hand side with `.`. See `` help(`%>%`) `` for more.

Unfortunately, because of this misunderstanding, `try` is not functioning as you expect. However, I think that may be another question.

Comment: Thanks, I don;t think I would have figured that out on my own! Do you know if it's possible to place the try at the end of my `index_name` function? Tried `df %>% {try(rename(!!! lookup[i1])})` but I cannot see where I'd place the dot here

Comment: I don't see a way to do what you want exclusively with pipes. There is the `%T>%` pipe, but I don't see how it could work. I think you have to try to assign the output of `rename` within the `try` call inside your custom function and then return the assigned value.

Comment: Ach! Sorry to un-accept. This does not work for df2, throws an error. `df2 %>% {try(index_name(.,lookup))} %>% glimpse`

Comment: To clarify, I'm using try() across a list of DFs, some of which may be NULL. In which case these should be skipped over/not throw an error

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do. But I tried to answer your question "Why does my function not seem to get applied when nested within try()?" I humbly suggest that if your actual question is more like "How can a attempt a call to `rename` and return the results even if there is an error?" that is likely a different question.